# Why is the public property not being serialized?

Tags: wcf, serialization, xsd

We have a WCF service which includes Serializable classes in a contract that has DataContract and DataMember at the root level of the service.

While trying to build a solution to isolate the problem, I came across the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract();

}


[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public MyType MyProperty { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class MyType
{
    private int amount1;

    [XmlElement(Form = XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "int", ElementName = "AmountN")]
    public int Amount1
    {
        get
        { return amount1; }
        set
        { amount1 = value; }
    }

 }
```

Gives the following xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="CompositeType">
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="MyProperty" type="tns:MyType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType><xs:element name="CompositeType" type="tns:CompositeType" nillable="true"/>
<xs:complexType name="MyType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="amount1" type="xs:int"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
 <xs:element name="MyType" type="tns:MyType" nillable="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Question is: Why is the private but not the public member being serialized?

Comment: Very old question but for those who wants  serialization like old asp.net web services can use  [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute as shown in following link.


http://www.developersalley.com/blog/post/2014/08/02/How-To-Force-WCF-Service-To-Use-XmlSerializer-Instead-Of-The-DataContractSerializer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializers and serialization attributes are two different things.

`XmlElement` is attribute for `XmlSerializer` but it has no meaning for `DataContractSerializer` or for `BinaryFormatter`. [XmlElementAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)

`DataContractSerializer` can serialize multiple types, but it uses own serialization algorithm [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx). When serializing objects marked with `[Serializable]`, 
`DataContractSerializer` follows default serialization pattern (serializing all members, `[NonSerialized]` applies). If you need more control then you can implement `ISerializable` for custom serialization and then you can set node names and values in serialized object [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) .

There is also an option to implement `IXmlSerializable` and have full control on how serialized object will look like.

Answer (score 1):

[This msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx) can explain, why wcf is able to serialize your MyType:

> Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer: . . .
>
> Types marked with the SerializableAttribute attribute. Many types
> included in the .NET Framework base class library fall into this
> category. The DataContractSerializer fully supports this serialization
> programming model that was used by .NET Framework remoting, the
> BinaryFormatter, and the SoapFormatter, including support for the
> ISerializable interface.

And since wcf have no problem to serialize private fields, probably this is the reason of serializing your privet field `amount1`.

INO, The question is **"why your property Amount1 was not serialized?**" I'd try to rename it (be different from field name), remove xml attributes on it, and re-try.

Comment: sorry about removing the accept, I have changed the name as per your recomendation, and added a bounty.